# Help Big-O proof troubles

Tags: asymptotics

I need to prove the rule that 
if $f(n) \in g(n) + O(h(n))$ then $g(n)\in f(n) + O(h(n))$

I have made several attempts but never get far as I'm not quite sure where to begin.

Comment: What does `E` mean to you?

Comment: Should E represent $\in$? I.e. Do you mean that the rule is: if $f(n) \in g(n) + O(h(n))$ then $g(n) \in f(n) + O(h(n))$?

Comment: I think you mean that $f(n)-g(n) \in O(h(n)) \Rightarrow g(n)-f(n) \in O(h(n))$, which is basically automatic since the two left sides have the same magnitude in the first place.